# Fatal error: Call to a member function getElementsByTagname() on null

Tags: php

```
if ($rows->length > 0) 
   {
     for ($i=1; $i<=$rows->length ; $i++) 
     {
        //echo($rows[$i]->getElementsByTagname('th'));
        $cols = $rows->item($i)->getElementsByTagname('td');
        for ($j=0; $j <$cols->length ; $j++) 
        { 
          //echo($cols[$j]->nodeValue);
          $input_lines = $cols[$j]->nodeValue;
          $input_lines =  preg_replace("/\D/", "", $input_lines);
          echo $input_lines;
          echo"<br><br>";

        }     
      }
    }
```

> **Fatal error:** Call to a member function `getElementsByTagname()` on null

Comment: is `$rows->item` an object method or attribute?

Comment: Can you show the echo $rows->item($i); ?

Answer (score 0):

The method `getElementsByTagName` may return NULL (acording to documentation [here](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php)), so you need to check for not-null variable:

```
$cols = $rows->item($i)
if( !null($cols)){
  $cols = $cols->getElementsByTagname('td')
}
else {
    throw new Exception("Element with name 'some name' was not found");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me better works : `$cols = $items->item($i); if($cols != NULL) {...`